# Call a Python file in a SML program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, call, sml, smlnj

I was wondering if it is possible to call a python file in an SML program, and if so how can you do it? I have tried researching how to do this, but have only found documentation on how to call other SML files.

Answer (score 4):

I think `OS.Process.system "python myscript.py"` should work. See: http://sml-family.org/Basis/os-process.html

Comment: I am receiving a tycon mismatch error when I try to implement this. I added my sml code as well as the error and the method in python I am trying to call. Can you see where I went wrong?

Comment: @arizq29, I suggest opening a new question that contains the complete SML code you're using too.

Comment: My entire SML code is contained in the link above. It is very short, I am just trying to call a method from a python file I wrote in SML. The link also includes the error I am receiving. The SML code is below the error.

Comment: @arizq29 why are you doing a recursive call? The problem is that you're taking the return value of `interpreter` (which is the return value of `OS.Process.system`, which is `OS_Process.status`), binding it to `s`, and then trying to concatenate (`^`) `s` with a string. That's the type mismatch.

Comment: Ok, so how would I go about calling the function in python using the arguments received from the SML function then? Would I just get rid of the concatenation so its OS.Process.system ("python interpreter.py")? That allows the sml program to compile and returns me this `val interpreter = fn : string * string -> Word32.word val it = () : unit` My program in python should output a text file, so is Word32.word the output I should expect?

Comment: Again, a separate question would be better. `OS.Process.system("python interpreter.py " ^ infile ^ " " ^ outfile)` is how you'd pass your arguments. Then the output is just a status (*not* stdout). Presumably your output will be at `outfile`.