# Call a Python Function within SML

Tags: python, python-3.x, call, sml, smlnj

I am trying to call a function from a python file I wrote in SML. I am receiving a tycon mismatch error and I don't understand why. This is my SML code

```
fun interpreter(inFile: string, outFile: string)=
let
    val s = interpreter(inFile, outFile)
in
    OS.Process.system ("python interpreter.py" ^ s)
end;
```

And this is the error I am receiving

```
- use "in.sml";
[opening in.sml]
in.sml:1.6-6.6 Error: right-hand-side of clause doesn't agree with function result type [tycon mismatch]
  expression:  ?.OS_Process.status
  result type:  string
  in declaration:
    interpreter =
      (fn (<pat> : string,<pat> : string) =>
            let val <binding> in OS.Process.system <exp> end)
val it = () : unit
```

This is the method in python I am trying to call:

```
def interpreter(input, output):
    x = Interpreter()
    x.interpreter(input, output)
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Call a Python file in a SML program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353918/call-a-python-file-in-a-sml-program). Please ask your questions once.

Comment: Please format blocks of code with indentation and not backticks. If you select text and press the `{}` button, it usually does the right thing.

Comment: That would never terminate since the evaluation depends on its own result.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is trying to reconcile the result/return type of `interpreter` which you are calling recursively here: `val s = interpreter(inFile, outFile)`. the compiler thinks `s` must be of type `string` since you are concatenating it with `^` but the body of the function you are returning the value returned by `OS.Process.system ("python interpreter.py" ^ s)` which must be `?.OS_Process.status`.

Comment: Ok, so how would I go about calling the function in python using the arguments received from the SML function then? Would I just get rid of the concatenation so its `OS.Process.system ("python interpreter.py")`? That allows the sml program to compile and returns me this `val interpreter = fn : string * string -> Word32.word
val it = () : unit` My program in python should output a text file, so is Word32.word the output I should expect?